# Cocoa: Pass arguments to NSApplicationDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, command-line-arguments

I have created the simple Cocoa application (Mac OS X 10.6) and there have appeared the entry point:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

and `AppDelegate` dummy:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // how to get argc and argv?
}
```

and some other. How could I pass the argc and argv to my `AppDelegate` right way?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `+[NSProcessInfo processInfo]` and `-[NSProcessInfo arguments]`.

In your application delegate,

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSArray *args = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
    // use -objectAtIndex: to obtain an element of the array
    // and -count to obtain the number of elements in the array
}
```