# use NSDocument application via command line

Tags: swift, macos, command-line-interface, nsdocument

here is the situation:

**Current situation**

I have an `NSDocument` application (macOS), which works currently only via the Graphical User Interface (GUI). The app is written in Swift 4.

**Wished situation**

I would like to offer a **Commande-Line Interface (CLI)** for the app which would take the `NSDocument` file (a config file actually) as argument.
The `NSDocument` is needed to access the data (stored using Core Data) inside.
When using the app via command-line, the GUI should not be started. The use is either via the GUI, or via the CLI.

**What I already know**

I think that I should rewrite `@NSApplicationMain` to be able to retrieve the app arguments, but I could not find any concrete example in Swift.

---

Has someone already done something similar and could give me a hint of how to achieve this, in Swift ? 
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa: Pass arguments to NSApplicationDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616959/cocoa-pass-arguments-to-nsapplicationdelegate)

Comment: Sorry but no, it does not explain how to get around ``@NSApplicationMain``, it is in Objective-C, and it just explains how to basically get the arguments of the app.

Comment: It's `ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments` in Swift. You can open the document with  `openDocument(withContentsOf:display:completionHandler:)` of `NSDocumentController` and terminate the app in the completion handler.

Comment: The other solution is a command line tool and a GUI wrapper.